# Difference between AWS ECS Service Type Daemon & Constraint "One Task Per Host"

Tags: amazon-web-services, task, amazon-ecs

On an initial look AWS ECS "Daemon" Service Type and the placement constraint "One Task per Host" looks very similar. Can someone please guide me on the differences between the two and some real life examples of when one is preferred over another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By "One Task Per Host" are you referring to the `distinctInstance` constraint?

`distinctInstance` means that no more than 1 instance of the task can be running on a server at a time. However the actual count of task instances across your cluster will depend on your desired task count setting. So if you have 3 servers in your cluster, you could have as little as 1 of the tasks running, and as much as 3 of the tasks running.

`daemon` specifies to ECS that one of these tasks has to be running on every server in the cluster. So if you have 3 servers in your cluster then you will have 3 instances of the task running, one on each server.

Comment: Interesting. I see the distinction. So, task level autoscaling is applicable to a service with "distinctInstance" constraint and autoscaling will not be applicable to a service spun up with "daemon" strategy as that goes hand in hand with the host.